# ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED nginx reactjs node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, server-error

Thanks to take 2 min to help me.

Here is my problem:
We currently developing a website with nginx, reactjs and node.js
Since some weeks we have this particular problem and we don't know where it come from :

Fully random our website is down, the browser prompt ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Sometimes there is no problem, the website is well and up, but 10 minutes later, it crash and display this error. Then it come back...in a loop.
We looked a lot on the web and didn't find a answer for us.

Please, if you know someting that can help us, let us know.
Thankful,
Mat

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off gzip encoding, that should solve the problem.

Then figure out which of your assets comes back not gzipped when it should be gzipped.

Without code, hard to tell you more. What is happening is that your browser is receiving a file it expects to be Gzip-encoded (according to the headers), but in fact is not encoded. It could have many causes, I suggest you deactivate gzip on your prod site and take the time to test on a dev server so as to not disrupt your operations. Good Luck!

Comment: My god, you are the hero. My case is that I try to implement early hints 103 and I totally have no idea that gzip is the culprit